# FFTW forward and back ward yield in different results why?

Tags: c++, fftw

I am trying to FFT an image using the library from http://www.fftw.org/. basically i want to do a forward transform and then the backward transform to get the input image i have chosen. Then I would like to get my input back with the backward FFT, but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
double n[w][h][2];
double im[w][h][2];

const int Lx = w;
 const int Lt = h;
 int var_x;
 int var_t;


 fftw_complex *in, *out, *result;
 fftw_plan p;
 fftw_plan inv_p;

 in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
 out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
 result = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *Lx *Lt);

 p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Lx, Lt, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);



 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         in[t + Lt*x][0] = n[x][t][0];
         in[t + Lt*x][1] = 0;
     }
 }

 fftw_execute(p);

 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         n[x][t][0] = out[t + Lt*x][0];
         n[x][t][1] = out[t + Lt*x][1];
     }
 }



 inv_p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Lx, Lt, out, result, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

 fftw_execute(inv_p);

 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         im[x][t][0] = result[t + Lt*x][0];
         im[x][t][1] = result[t + Lt*x][1];
         std::cout<<im[x][t][0]<<std::endl;
     }
 }

 fftw_destroy_plan(p);
 fftw_free(in);
 fftw_free(out);
```

As you can see, I just try to perform a normal FFT, then to reverse it. The problem is that my output 'im' is just full of 0, instead of 1 and 0...

So what's wrong with my code ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Didn't you already ask this same question yesterday? I think I commented that you were neglecting to zero the imaginary parts of the input?

Comment: @Paul: I have made the imaginary part zero but still i see no difference, the result is still the same. is that i am missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected version of the code which is now working - thank you to everybody who helped me to fix all the problems.

```
 double n[w][h][2];
 double im[w][h][2];

 const int Lx = w;
 const int Lt = h;
 int var_x;
 int var_t;

 fftw_complex *in, *out, *result;
 fftw_plan p;
 fftw_plan inv_p;

 in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
 out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Lx*Lt);
 result = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) *Lx *Lt);

 p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Lx, Lt, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         in[t + Lt*x][0] = n[x][t][0];
         in[t + Lt*x][1] = 0;
     }
 }

 fftw_execute(p);

 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         n[x][t][0] = out[t + Lt*x][0];
         n[x][t][1] = out[t + Lt*x][1];
     }
 }

 inv_p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(Lx, Lt, out, result, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

 fftw_execute(inv_p);

 for (int x = 0; x < Lx; x++)
 {
     for (int t = 0; t < Lt; t++)
     {
         im[x][t][0] = result[t + Lt*x][0];
         im[x][t][1] = result[t + Lt*x][1];
         std::cout<<im[x][t][0]<<std::endl;
     }
 }

 fftw_destroy_plan(p);
 fftw_destroy_plan(inv_p);
 fftw_free(in);
 fftw_free(out);
 fftw_free(result);
```

Comment: but this is the answer i have checked it and i get the expected result in the end. By corrected version i mean after making all corrections the updated code. Do you find any mistakes in that case please point them out so that i can correct them.

Comment: OK - sorry - it wasn't clear from the limited context - I've added some clarification to the answer and removed my down-vote. (I've also deleted two additional `fftw_free` calls which should not have been present.)

Answer (score 0):

Your original image and transform matrices are declared as `int`. Try defining them as `double`:

```
double n[w][h][2];
double im[w][h][2];
```

The line below, for example, is destroying data because `result[i][j]` is of type `double` (as of `fftw_complex` [definition](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html)). So that if `result[i][j] == 0.99`, it'll be converted to 0.

```
im[x][t][0] = result[t + Lt*x][0]; //A value of 0.99 may be converted to 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. but i still cannot figure out why i still get only zeros i guess i am missing something else but i am unable to solve it can you please help?.

Comment: Well, I can't see anywhere in the code the initialization of values in matrix `n`.  Have you checked the contents of n[] before running the first loop? Notice that by default the compiler may initialize it to zeros.