# FFT returns NaN values

Tags: c, double, fftw

I'm trying to use the FFTW for my large project, so I wrote a basic program to check if the FFT is working or not. I am trying to send sine values to the FFT and back. After using the FFT forwards and FFT backwards I get exactly the same results, but I get a NaN value at the first element of the array. I read in some of the questions here that the issue is the data type, I need to use `long double` and `fftwl` to maintain accuracy of the results.
Where is the problem? Is it in the data type and how can I solve it?

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

int Ypt=128;
long double PI=3.14159265358979323846;

void complex2FFT( complex long double *U)
{
  long double normalizing_factor= 2.0/Ypt;
  fftwl_plan plan_f;
  fftwl_complex *in;
  fftwl_complex *out;

  in  = (fftwl_complex *) fftwl_malloc(sizeof(fftwl_complex) * Ypt);
  out = (fftwl_complex *) fftwl_malloc(sizeof(fftwl_complex) * Ypt);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    in[i ][0]= creal(U[i]);
    in[i ][1]= cimag(U[i]);
  }

  plan_f = fftwl_plan_dft_1d(Ypt, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD , FFTW_ESTIMATE);

  fftwl_execute(plan_f);

  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    U[i] = normalizing_factor*out[i][0] + normalizing_factor*out[i][1]*I;
  }

  fftwl_destroy_plan(plan_f);
  fftwl_free(in);
  fftwl_free(out);
  fftwl_cleanup();
}

void FFT2complex( complex long double *U)
{
  long double normalizing_factor= 1.0;
  fftwl_plan plan_b;
  fftwl_complex *in;
  fftwl_complex *out;

  in  = (fftwl_complex *) fftwl_malloc(sizeof(fftwl_complex) * Ypt);
  out = (fftwl_complex *) fftwl_malloc(sizeof(fftwl_complex) * Ypt);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    out[i ][0]= creal(U[i]);
    out[i ][1]= cimag(U[i]);
  }

  plan_b = fftwl_plan_dft_1d(Ypt, in, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    U[i] = normalizing_factor*in[i ][0] + normalizing_factor*in[i ][1]*I;
  }

  fftwl_execute(plan_b);

  fftwl_destroy_plan(plan_b);
  fftwl_free(in);
  fftwl_free(out);
  fftwl_cleanup();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  long double dy=( (long double)1)  / ( (long double)Ypt);
  complex long double *U = malloc(Ypt * sizeof(*U)); 
  complex long double *V = malloc(Ypt * sizeof(*V)); 

  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    U[i] = sin( (double) (2.0*PI* (double)i * dy)) ;
    V[i] = sin( (double) (2.0*PI* (double)i * dy)) ;
  }

  char name[45];
  FILE *stream;
  sprintf(name, "V%d.txt", 0);
  stream= fopen(name,"w");

  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    fprintf(stream, "%Lf %2.5f %2.5f \n", (long double)i*dy,creal(U[i]),cimag(U[i]));
  }
       
  complex2FFT(U);

  FFT2complex(U);

  for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
    fprintf(stream, "%Lf %2.5f %2.5f \n", (long double)i*dy,creal(U[i]),cimag(U[i]) );
  }

  free(U);
  free(V);
}
```

Comment: `fftwl_execute(plan_b)` runs after you copy the output.

Comment: I change it and still get NaN values. The thing is, if I use Ypt=16, I don't get any nan values but for Ypt=32,128 I get nan values

Comment: Hmmm, `U[i] = sin( ...) ;  V[i] = sin( ...) ;}` --> I'd expect one of those to use `cos()`.

Comment: `V[]` is allocated, set and free'd, but never used.  Why is it in the code?

Comment: I'm using V[] to compare the values of Sin(U) before and after fft_forward and fft_backward. So, I sign the values of sine to U and V then fft U and compare the results

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @Dietrich Epp ,  `fftwl_execute(plan_b)` runs after the output is copied, therefore the output  is left unchanged. In addition, `FFTW_BACKWARD` performs the backward DFT, but it does not mean that the argument `in` is used as output. Even with flag `FFTW_BACKWARD`, the input argument of [`fftw_plan_dft_1d()`](https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html) is `in` and the output is `out`.
See for instance that example of forward then backward transform : [FFTW forward and back ward yield in different results why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482531/fftw-forward-and-back-ward-yield-in-different-results-why)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
  out[i ][0]= creal(U[i]);
  out[i ][1]= cimag(U[i]);
}

plan_b = fftwl_plan_dft_1d(Ypt, out, in, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftwl_execute(plan_b);
for (int i = 0; i < Ypt; ++i){
  U[i] = normalizing_factor*in[i ][0] + normalizing_factor*in[i ][1]*I;
}
```